# Hoe to get data based onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Based on onClick function I want to get data for the particular user.
What I tried to create a function getSelectedData and tried to called by passing current data as an argument.

But received only the last value of the array.

```
function getSelectedData(receiveData){
  console.log(receiveData)
}

var card = document.getElementById('mainBody')

var x = ""
for(var i = 0; i <= user.length -1; i++){
 var UserData = user[i]
    x = x +`
    <div class="card m-2 d-flex flex-column align-items-center" onclick="getSelectedData(UserData)">
            <img src="${user[i].userImage}" alt="" class="UserImage my-3"/>
            <p class="userName">${user[i].userName}</p>
            <p class="userCountry">${user[i].userCountry}</p>
            <p class="userProfession">${user[i].userProfession}</p>
    </div>` ;
}
card.innerHTML = x
```

Comment: If I've understood correctly, you are rendering a div to the page that is populated with user data you've retrieved from somewhere else. When the user clicks on that div, you want a function called `getSelectedData` to fire. Is that right? Your onclick event should fire and execute your function but the argument `UserData` will not have value unless you put something there referencing the data you need. Your function can then process the data but, will tell you nothing you didn't already have to know to populate the div. Perhaps you really only need to know which user div has been clicked?

Answer (score 1):

By the time `getSelectedData` is actually called, the value in `UserData` is the last value assigned to it.

If instead you had used

```
... onclick="getSelectedData(` + UserData + `)"...
```

each `onclick` would have the value of `UserData` at the time you were adding to `x`.

UPDATE: As pointed out, `UserData` is an object.  Since `user` isn't defined in this code, it would presumably be available to `getSelectedData`, and thus one could use:

```
... onclick="getSelectedData(user[` + i + `])"...
```

Comment: I think UserData is an object.

Comment: Would UserData be passed to getSelectedData properly like this? I would think he would need to pass it in like this: getSelectedData('' + UserData) ??

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting a new user, similar to this innerHTML. This is an inappropriate way because it overrides all content. You may use this "appendChild" like this "card.appendChild"

Comment: As true as this might be, it does not seem to address the question being asked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your `onclick` attribute will fire but the argument `UserData` will not hold any value unless you put it there. One solution, demonstrated in my working snippet below, is to send the div itself to the function using the `this` reference. In your function, you then extract the values you need by retrieving the div's child elements collection and reading the values back that you previously put there.

```js
const user = [
  {userName: "John", userCountry: "France", userProfession: "musician", userImage: "001.png"},
  {userName: "Jane", userCountry: "Germany", userProfession: "Teacher", userImage: "005.png"},
  {userName: "Peter", userCountry: "Italy", userProfession: "Mechanic", userImage: "021.png"}
  ];

function processUser(element) {
  let user = element.children[1].innerHTML;
  console.log(`user is ${user}`);
  let country = element.children[2].innerHTML;
  let occupation = element.children[3].innerHTML;
  let image = element.children[0].src;
  console.log(`${user} lives in ${country}, their occupation is ${occupation}`);
  console.log(`${user}'s picture: ${image}`)
}

for(let i=0; i < user.length; i++){
  let markup = "";
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute("class", "card");
  div.setAttribute("onclick", "processUser(this)");
  markup += `<img src="${user[i].userImage}" alt="" class="UserImage my-3"></img>`;
  markup += `<p class="userName">${user[i].userName}</p>`;
  markup += `<p class="userCountry">${user[i].userCountry}</p>`;
  markup += `<p class="userProfession">${user[i].userProfession}</p>`;
  div.innerHTML = markup;
  
document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
body {
 background: yellow;
}
div {
 border: 1px solid red;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 10px;
 background: white;
}
img {
  width:40px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>click any of the divs:</p>
```

That works, and achieves what I think you want to. I'd maybe have chosen a different approach if you can add numerical IDs to your user objects in your data array to the same value as the index for that user object, you could set the ID of the div to the same (number) and just send that back to your function using `(this.id)` as the argument to the onlick event. That ID can then be used to read your data array for the relevant user `user[retrievedID].name` etc.